# When saving an object from the django admin panel, I get error 400

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When I create an object in django admin when I click save, nothing happens, I get an error.
Request URL:
/api/admin/advertisements/advertisements/add/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request

Request sent to a non existent address, I didn't redefine anything, no validation happens.
Everything is fine with the other models. There is nothing wrong with the venv environment. The code of this model is standard.

```
class Advertisements(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, verbose_name="User", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategories, verbose_name="Subcategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
   class Meta:
        verbose_name = "advertisement"
        verbose_name_plural = "dvertisements"
```

Comment: Full stacktrace please. Also have you made sure that this model exists in the database? I mean you should check manually if you can...

Comment: By the way you have typo:   verbose_name_plural = "dvertisements". Should be advertisements probably.

Comment: Bad request 400 happens sometime, restart your server and also hard refresh the page by `Ctrl+f5`, if its doesn't fix it,kindly check your table exist in database or not, also run `makemigrations` and `migrate` one time to see.

Comment: My table exists in the database, migrations are fine. I cannot provide an error, because this error does not exist at all. All I get is 400

Comment: Did you correct the typo? Makes me nervous :/

Comment: dvertisements -> advertisements